# Maximum distance between two related shapefiles

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have two shapefiles of points, the first one with the point's name and the second one with several points and each point with a name of the first shapefile point. I need to measure the farthest point from the second shapefile for each point in the first shape. 
For example I have 7 points with the name A and 8 point with the name B. I need from those 7 point with the name A, the farthest point and the distance between A and the specific point. And from those 8 points with the name B, the farthest distance between B and farthest point.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a set of instructions to find the maximum distance per Name between the two Point layers:

Run "Add XY Coordinates" on each feature class.
Join the single name Point featureclass to the multiple names featureclass.
Create lines connecting the matching Points using "XY to Line".
Find the maximum distance per Name by running "Summary Statistics".

If you need the Points that makeup the max distance, join the "Summary Statistics" table to the Line Featureclass. You may need to build a composite join key by concatenating Name + MaxDistance.
Once you have the max Lines, you can "Select by Location" to select the underlying Points.